# Questions about cluster $\mathcal{X}$-varieties and amalgamation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cluster-algebras

I am trying to learn the amalgamation of two cluster seeds and  I am reading the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0508408.pdf written by V.V. Fock and A. B. Goncharov.  I am at a loss for the Lemma 2.2. on page 9.[image]

My question is (a) I don't find a function $c$ on $K$.

(b) I don't understand the proof of Lemma 2.2, who can explain it clearly? Or offer me some relative papers. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why someone vote down my question? Maybe this question  is very clear but  I just want to get some relative papers and helps to solve this question.

Comment: This seems to be a misprint. The $c$ should be a $d$ and also $s\in C$ should be $s\in K$. Then the existence of $d$ is just what is stated in condition (iii) and uniqueness is obvious because the $I(s)$ cover $K$.